# elatic apm, django integration, user id

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elastic-apm

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/django-support.html

Is there a way to include user-id for apm messages?

We'd like to know if how many unique users are experiencing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! You can use [`elasticapm.set_custom_context()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html#api-set-custom-context) or [`elasticapm.label()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/python/current/api.html#api-label) to add this kind of context to your events.

Keep in mind that labels are indexed, which has performance implications, while context is not indexed but is present and viewable in Elasticsearch. More info [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/7.6/metadata.html).